# NoMethodError at /signup.html undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass while running Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I migrated my Rails application from 3.2.13 to 4.0.0, but while running the application, I am getting the error:

> Started GET "/signup.html" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-06-29 17:28:16 +0530 
>   ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT
>   "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations" Processing by
>   AccountsController#new as HTML   Parameters: {"plan"=>"year"}
>   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 51ms
>   ** [Airbrake] Notice was not sent due to configuration:            Environment Monitored? false            API key set? true
>
> NoMethodError - undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass:
>
>   activemerchant (1.47.0) lib/active_merchant/billing/model.rb:11:in`
>   initialize'   app/controllers/accounts_controller.rb:83:in
>   `load_billing'   activesupport (4.0.0)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:437:in`
>   _run__3203841093432473566__process_action__callbacks'   activesupport
>   (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
>
>   actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in`
>   process_action'   actionpack (4.0.0)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
>   .......................................

This is my controller code :

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController

  #inherit_resources
  ssl_required :new, :create
  before_filter :load_billing, :only => [:new, :create]

  def new
    @account_name = Rails.application.config.custom.accounts.send(params[:account_name]).name
    @account_signup_message = Rails.application.config.custom.accounts.send(params[:account_name]).signup_message
  rescue
    nil
  end

  def create
    @address.first_name = @creditcard.first_name
    @address.last_name = @creditcard.last_name
    @account.address = @address
    @account.creditcard = @creditcard

    if @account.new_record?
      if @account.save
        flash[:notice] = 'Account was created.'
        sign_in(@user, :bypass => true)
        redirect_to session[:previous_url] || user_reports_path(@user)
      else
        render :action => 'new'
      end
    else
      @user.account_id = @account.id
      if @user.save
        flash[:notice] = 'User was created.'
        sign_in(@user, :bypass => true)
        redirect_to session[:previous_url] || user_reports_path(@user)
      else
        render :action => 'new'
      end
    end
  end

  protected

  def load_billing
    @creditcard = ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(params[:account].blank? ? nil : params[:account][:creditcard]) #This is the line it is showing error.
    @address = SubscriptionAddress.new(params[:account].blank? ? nil : params[:account][:address])
  end

end
```

routes.rb:

```
get '/signup'   => 'accounts#new'
```

accounts/new.html.erb:

```
<%= semantic_form_for(@account, :url => account_create_path, :html => { :multipart => true, :class => 'billing'}) do |f| %>

  <%= f.inputs :for => :user do |u| %>
     #name and email fields are mentioned.
  <% end %>

  <%= f.inputs :for => :creditcard do |c| %>
     #name, card_no, cvv, expire_date etc;
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This is my activemerchant (1.47.0) lib/active_merchant/billing/model.rb:

```
require "active_merchant/billing/compatibility"
require "active_merchant/empty"

module ActiveMerchant
  module Billing
    class Model
      include Compatibility::Model
      include Empty

      def initialize(attributes = {})
        attributes.each do |key, value|
          send("#{key}=", value)
        end
      end

      def validate
        {}
      end

      private

      def errors_hash(array)
        array.inject({}) do |hash, (attribute, error)|
          (hash[attribute] ||= []) << error
          hash
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

*include Empty* is the error showing line in the above code. And there is no model.rb file for activemerchant version 1.20.4 (my previous).
Please help me.

Comment: From looking at your error message I can tell that the issue is in a callback on lib/active_merchant/billing/model.rb:11.  On that line, whatever you are calling .each on doesn't exist.  Post the code from that file if you are still confused

Comment: I updated in the question. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveMerchant.new requires an hash of attributes and their values(default is empty hash), but you are passing nil which is causing the error. Check [this](https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/blob/master/lib/active_merchant/billing/model.rb#L11) implementation for better understanding. I think that you need not pass anything(not even nil) if params[:account][:creditcard] is not present.

Comment: The same thing is working in Rails 3.2. Does Active Merchant code differs with version change?

Comment: @user3189916 I donno. You will have to check the docs for the version that you are using. Please refer this tutorial https://richonrails.com/articles/credit-card-processing-with-active-merchant

Comment: I didn't find model.rb file in my previous one 1.20.4, but it is having initialize method in the new version. Can you please give example on the answer you given?

Comment: It may be working in your other case because the account params are never blank.

Answer (score 2):

"include Empty is the error showing line in the above code. "  No it is raising an exception on line 11 which is " `attributes.each do |key, value|`"  because attributes is nil.

So change this line:

```
@creditcard = ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(params[:account].blank? ? nil : params[:account][:creditcard])
```

to this:

```
@creditcard = ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(params[:account].blank? ? {} : params[:account][:creditcard])
```

now you will be sending through something that won't raise if you call .each on it.

```
foo = {}
 => {} 
2.3.0 :002 > foo.each {|key, value| puts "#{key}=#{value}" }
 => {}
```

But just so that you understand:

In the initialize method this line

```
def initialize(attributes = {})
```

initializes an instance of the class with a default parameter of an empty hash if no other parameter is being passed in.  In your ternary on this line:

```
@creditcard = ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(params[:account].blank? ? nil : params[:account][:creditcard])
```

this:

```
params[:account].blank? ? nil : params[:account][:creditcard]
```

says that if there are no account params, send nil as a parameter to initialize.  The nil value overwrites the default({}) value and you get undefined method each on nil class because you are calling:

```
attributes.each do |key, value|
```

but you have defined attributes as nil.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close square brackets on before_action call.